# opencv-python cv2.imread() return a NoneType

Tags: python, opencv

I try to use `cv2.imread('~/Download/image.jpg')` to read an image, but it always returned a `NoneType`. It seems that this function can not read any image. I am pretty sure that the path is right. Does anyone know something?
Thanks

Comment: You can try `os.path.exists()` to make sure a file (or directory) exists.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! We might be able to better answer your question if you include your code in the text of the question. Just paste it in, select it, and then click the `{ }` button to automatically format it.

Answer (score 2):

The ***filename*** param need to be a absolute/relative path, so, you need use ***/home/username/*** instead ***~***.

Check [imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread) documentation.

If you need to use ***~***, you can try expanduser:

```
from os.path import expanduser
filename = expanduser("~") + '/Download/image.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
```

Python3.6

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = f'{str(Path.home())}/Download/image.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You mentioned something that I didn't know in python. I will try it later. In fact, I made a naive mistake that is the image file was broken. I try another image and it worked. Thanks anyway!